# Consuming Asynchronous Service in AngularJS 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty new to angular world. Creating singleton service to consume in my controller. service code is below

```
      function obiUrlService(remote, SERVER_URL, URI, OBI_URL) {
      this.obiUrl = this.getObiurl;
       this.getObiurl = function() {
       remote
         .get(SERVER_URL + URI.obiDocumentViewer + '/' + OBI_URL.obiUrl)
         .then(function(data) {
          return data;
       });
     };
    }
```

Note: remote is a seperate service am consuming here.

I wanted my controller to consume this service something like-

```
    vm.myurlData = obiUrlService.obiUrl;
```

Comment: JavaScript does non-blocking I/O. The `remote` service can not return data it can only return a promise from which data needs to be extracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript does non-blocking I/O. The remote service can not return data. It can only return a promise from which data gets extracted.

```
app.service("obiUrlService",
  function obiUrlService(remote, SERVER_URL, URI, OBI_URL) {
    ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶.̶o̶b̶i̶U̶r̶l̶ ̶=̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶.̶g̶e̶t̶O̶b̶i̶u̶r̶l̶;̶
    this.getObiUrl = function() {
      return remote
        .get(SERVER_URL + URI.obiDocumentViewer + '/' + OBI_URL.obiUrl);
        ̶.̶t̶h̶e̶n̶(̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶(̶d̶a̶t̶a̶)̶ ̶{̶
         ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶;̶
       ̶}̶)̶;̶
  };
})
```

In controller:

```
obiUrlService.getObiUrl.then(function(data) {
  vm.myurlData = data;
});
```